# build.gradleのpluginsとdependenciesについて

Tags: gradle

pluginsとdependenciesの違いが分かりません。
開発するうえで使いたいものはすべてdependenciesにまとめればいいのではないでしょうか？
なぜpluginsが存在しているのかも分からず、dependenciesとどう区別すればよいのかもわからないです。